# Writing a sorting method for any Collection of Comparables (Java)

Tags: java, sorting, collections

This is my first post on Stack Overflow. If there is anything I can do to improve it: please share.

I am trying to learn about different sorting algorithms (such as insertion, selection, bubble, merge, quick, bucket, radix, heap, shell, gnome, and bogo sort) and implement them in Java.

How could I write a sort method which will work with any class that implements `Collection` of any class that implements `Comparable`? I looked at the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.sort%28java.util.List%29) of `Collections.sort()` and it has some syntax in the method signature I don't understand.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list) {
    Object[] a = list.toArray();
    Arrays.sort(a);
    ListIterator<T> i = list.listIterator();
    for (int j=0; j<a.length; j++) {
        i.next();
        i.set((T)a[j]);
    }
}
```

The following is my best (pathetic) guess of how to write a `SortNone` method, which doesn't sort a `Collection`, but has the correct method header to do so. I would call it with `SortNone.sort(myCollection)` where `myCollection` is an instance of any class implementing `Collection` of a Class implementing `Comparable` (assuming the prior import of `com.tenembasj.sort.*`, see More Info).

```
package com.tenembasj.sort;

public class SortNone {

    public static<T> void sort(Collection<E> collection) { //don't know how to require the object (is it T or E?) to implement Comparable
        //code to sort
        //would I have to use collection.size(), .get(i), .set(i), and such to edit the class implementing Collection?
    }
}
```

Furthermore, I would like to add a `sort` method which adds a parameter for a `Comparator`, I just need to know what the formal parameter would be. I think I can figure out the implementation once I know how to write the regular `sort`.

Again, I am trying to write my own sorting methods and not use `Collections.sort()`, `Arrays.sort()`, or any `Java.util` method. You might say "Don't reinvent the wheel", but I'm just trying to learn.

More Info

I would like to export these methods to a jar when I'm done and import them as a library in my future projects. I made a new project (in Eclipse), created a package called `com.tenembasj.sort`, and will add classes such as `MergeSort`. I believe this is standard naming convention, but if it isn't please tell me. My goal is to be able to type `import com.tenembasj.sort.*` in any of my future projects and call `MergeSort.sort(myCollection);` or `MergeSort.sort(myCollection, myComparator);`.

Comment: Please be specific about the question ? What exactly is your question.?

Comment: There are a lot of questions implied by what you've posted. Break it down and ask one at a time, and you'll be more likely to get useful answers.

Comment: Try separating the question. For example, if user 1 knows how to answer quest 2, but not quest 1 of your post, he might not reply. If you seperate the questions into different posts, you are more likely to get a correct answer faster.

Comment: You're not going to be able to sort an arbitrary `Collection` in-place; you can only sort a `List`.

Comment: @Dileep "How could I write a sort method which will work with any class that implements Collection of any class that implements Comparable?"

Comment: @keshlam Thank you for your input. I thought it would be better to include all of the questions here so people wouldn't have to read all of the background information on separate questions. If this isn't solved in a bit I will attempt to split it up and/or revise my question.

Comment: @rockinfresh Thank you for your input. I thought it would be better to include all of the questions here so people wouldn't have to read all of the background information on separate questions. If this isn't solved in a bit I will attempt to split it up and/or revise my question.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thank you, I will look up the difference between `Collection` and `List` and revise my answer.

Comment: If you websearch "implement java comparable sort", you'll find a number of examples -- including past discussion here on StackOverflow. The Related column, at right, has some related past discussion. (The most important difference between Collection and List for our purposes right now is that general Collections do not promise to retain order and hence can't be reliably put in order by sort or anything else; Lists are a subfamily of Collections which do consider order meaningful. Of course you could sort from a Collection _into_ a List...)

Answer (score 1):

***How could I write a sort method which will work with any class that implements Collection of any class that implements Comparable?***

For writing a function that can be applied to all type of objects, You must write a generic code like the code that you posted above from the source of Collections.sort().

Assuming that you are a beginner, the best place to start is to learn from [generic](http://www.journaldev.com/1663/java-generics-tutorial-example-class-interface-methods-wildcards-and-much-more) and eat the elephant one bite at a time.

---

*I will try to explain the code you have posted above.*

`T` means of any type in generic

`extends Comparable<? super T>` means that T must be a Comparable object. It can be of type `Object` that extends a `Comparable` interface or any object that contain a comparable interface.

`sort(List<T> list)` Means sort function can accept any `List` of objects of type `T` as argument.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list) {

//  Copying the values from the List of objects to an array.
    Object[] a = list.toArray();

//  Applying the array.sort operation.
    Arrays.sort(a);

//  Setting the values from the sorted array to the listi of type T. 
    ListIterator<T> i = list.listIterator();
    for (int j=0; j<a.length; j++) {
        i.next();
        i.set((T)a[j]);
    }
}
```

Start by learning the [generic](http://www.journaldev.com/1663/java-generics-tutorial-example-class-interface-methods-wildcards-and-much-more)

Comment: Thank you very much! I am reading about generics and collections vs. lists. One thing that I noticed is that the keyword `extends` is used, why wouldn't one use `implements`? Isn't `Comparable` an interface?

Comment: @hcps-tenembasj `Comparable` is an interface, but the `T` must contains the implementations for the Comparable Interface.